# How to create a bash alias to launch gvim on the .bash_aliases file and resource it when the editor completes?

Tags: bash, vim, jobs

I'd like to have a single alias which launches `gvim ~/.bash_aliases` and then re-sources the file after gvim exits (`. ~/.bash_aliases`)

For example,...

```
alias newaliases="gvim ~/.bash_aliases && . ~/.bash_aliases"
```

or perhaps...

```
alias newaliases="gvim ~/.bash_aliases ; . ~/.bash_aliases"
```

However in both examples, gvim runs, of course, asynchronously. This in turn causes the second command to be run as soon as gvim is launched rather than when gvim finishes.

I *could* discover the gvim's pid and run `wait pid` prior to re-sourcing. But that seems a bit tedious (e.g., I would need to guarantee I've got the pid of the *correct* gvim instance). Perhaps it is the only solution?

Comment: Notice that you have access to the correct PID with `$!`, so it might be as simple as `gvim; wait $!`

Comment: @BenjaminW. You only get `$!` if you run the program in the background with `&`. if the program forks a background process itself, you can't wait for that.

Comment: You can't use `wait pid` if the PID is not a child of the shell. In this case, it's a grandchild.

Comment: Oh dang, that's right, too bad!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `-f` option to `gvim`, which makes it run in the foreground, so the next command won't run until you finish editing.

> `-f`
> Foreground. For the GUI version, `Vim` will not fork and detach from the shell it was started in. ... This option should be used when `Vim` is executed by a program that will wait for the edit session to finish (e.g. mail).

Comment: I did gvim --help and missed it! How on Earth did I not see that??? I just did it a second time and I still missed it! Need to get my eyes checked!

Comment: I used the web version of the man page, and searched for "GUI" to see if there were options related to it.